# Model with "Integer Inflated" distribution Y

Tags: distributions, mixed-model, model

Forgive the poor statistical lexicon, I am a naturalist.

I am trying to find the best link function to build a model to estimate a response variable (Y) that has what I called an "Integer Inflated" Distribution.

Values usually assumes integer numbers but less often they can assume values in between (see below).
The reason of the following distribution is that the original value should only be integer, but sometimes there is uncertainty in the scoring so I calculate the mean of the values.

So far I used a Gaussian link function but as you can imagine the residuals do not look normally distributed.

What would you try? Is my only chance round the values an integer and use a Poisson model?

[image: My integer inflated distribution]

Comment: If $X=4.5$ means that your response took a value of either 4 or 5, the correct likelihood contribution from such an observation would be $P(4\le X \le 5)=P(X=4)+P(X=5)$ as function of the model parameters.  So what you have is interval censored discrete data.  If the rest of the model otherwise is some kind of glm such as Poisson regression, one could easily write the code maximising the total likelihood with this complication accounted for.

Comment: @JarleTufto  I think you got the point. Do you have any example of how to implement your suggestion in R? (I am using the package brms and a Bayesian approach)

Comment: Well, some googling suggest that interval senored data is now implemented in bmrs: https://github.com/paul-buerkner/brms/issues/93

Comment: @JarleTufto The posts are from 2016...maybe now would be available?! Do you know of any other package able to implement this?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit quick to conclude that it was not implemented - it seems that it is if you read the whole thread.  But I guess you're better off asking on the bmrs github forum about details.

Comment: "sometimes there is uncertainty in the scoring so I calculate the mean of the values." What exactly does that mean? The means of what values are calculated?

Answer (score 0):

What data do you have? If the numbers are rounded up to, say, 0.1 then it will make sense to fit a Poisson distribution to the numbers multiplied by 10. You may also try binomial distribution, negative binomial, etc.

If you want to fit a continuous distribution then you may consider normal, lognormal, gamma, Weibull, Pareto, Box-Cox distributions.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However multiply the data by 10 and use poisson would not solve the problems because some values would be definitely over-represented (see my figure).

Comment: It  cannot work (at least not without further modification). If the original values were very like a Poisson, then variance would be very close to mean. If you multiply by 10 variance is now very far from the mean and a Poisson model is no longer suitable.